# Custom Qt widget with discrete allowed widths

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create a custom widget in QT that is, essentially, a grid. I would like to allow this widget to be resized, but only so long as all boxes in the grid are of the same width and height. For example, if the grid is 30x20, then the widget need only be able to have widths that divide by 30 and heights that divide by 20.

I did not find anything in the size policy that seems like what I'm trying to do.

I know that X11 does support such size policies. Then again, it also supports defining aspect ratio ranges for top level windows, so that does not, necessarily, mean that Qt supports it too :-)

I know I can catch the resize signal, and then round down the size given. I think this might have unpleasant effects if used inside a broader layout, though. For example, placing two of those one next to the other might cause an infinite loop.

Thanks,
Shachar

Comment: Why don't you reimplement resizeEvent?

Comment: @saeed: For the reasons stated in the question itself. By the time resizeEvent is called, the widget has already resized. If I resize it again at this point, the entire display will need to be layed out again. If two such widgets are in the same layout, one might trigger the other, triggering the first one again etc.